# Change 1 hyperlink mouse over colour not in css but html

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, mouseover

I have my code at the moment....

```
<td> <a href="http://www.canvasbay.co.uk/pages.php?pID=5&CDpath=0">Get Started!</a></td>
```

The colours for the hyperlinks are in a css stylesheet however i want this specific TD different so i use the following...

```
<td> <a style="color: #800000" href="<?php echo tep_href_link(FILENAME_DEFAULT); ?>"><?php echo MENU_TEXT_HOME;?></a></td>
```

This works for the colour, however how do i change the mouse over colour ?

I tried to make another entry into the stylesheet by copying the original and changing the letter but this didn't work, my original stylesheet is below...

CSS

```
 a { 
      color: #000000; 
      text-decoration: none; 
      font-weight: normal; 
      }
      a:hover { 
      color: #ed1c24;
      text-decoration: none; 
      }
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always apply a class to the `<td>` element itself:

```
<td class="myClass"> <a href="http://www.canvasbay.co.uk/pages.php?pID=5&CDpath=0">Get Started!</a></td>
```

And then modify the css to only target the `a` element in that class:

```
.myClass a { 
      color: #000000; 
      text-decoration: none; 
      font-weight: normal; 
      }
.myClass a:hover { 
      color: #ed1c24;
      text-decoration: none; 
      }
```

Comment: I like this solution however the second should that have

    .myclass a:hover {
thanks

Comment: +1 for this solution. You can't use pseudo selectors (ie `:hover`) inline, so including the style in an external stylesheet or in a style block in the head is the way to go.

Comment: I have now successfully used this solution, many many thanks, awesome just what i wanted A+ :)

Comment: Glad to hear it helped! I've tweaked my reply so that the missing class selector on the :hover is fixed.

Comment: Many thanks for that, i am just happy i noticed a small error, i am very new to this and learning v.slowely :) I love how fast this site is at helping :)

Answer (score 1):

You can put an ID or class to the td and target only that

```
.myachor a:hover{color:#FFF !important;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this like

```
.specialtd:hover
{
color: #ed1c24 !important;
text-decoration: none; 
}

<td class="specialtd"> <a style="color: #800000" href="<?php echo tep_href_link(FILENAME_DEFAULT); ?>"><?php echo MENU_TEXT_HOME;?></a></td>
```